# How to run python code with support of GPU

Tags: python, flask, artificial-intelligence, gpu

I have created a flask service for accepting requests with camera URLs as parameters for finding objects(table, chair etc...) in the camera frame. I have written code in flask for accepting POST requests.

```
@app.route('/rest/detectObjects', methods=['GET','POST'])
def detectObjects()
...
json_result = function_call_for_detecting_objects()
...
return
```

In the function, its loads the tf model for object detection and returns the result. A large amount of request needs to be processed simultaneously by the flask server. So I need to execute the function using GPU as the camera access time and image processing for object detection takes much time and CPU utilization. Have a 4 GB GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2. How can I make my python script to make use of GPU for this?

Comment: This question is extremely unclear, what are you actually trying to calculate, what is the format of your inputs, etc. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first.

Comment: You should try to read this article before https://medium.com/3blades-blog/an-introduction-to-gpu-programming-with-python-637818be6f7d and then rewrite your question.

Comment: @Bas Jansen Edited the question.

Comment: I think you need to know how a function must be called in which it must access your gpu for processing the function. Right?

Comment: Yes. When I run the function the CPU usage is going maximum and when execution completes it is going normally. So high processing is needed for executing it. That's why I need to run this on GPU.

Comment: Finally got it. It was basically an issue of threading. While using the threading and capturing camera the usage is increasing high. If the same is done with multiprocessing or without any threading usage is normal. that's why CPU usage was abnormal.  While running the script, the gpu was not detected initially. later I have made proper driver installed and make it detectable for the script.

Answer (score 1):

To utilize the GPU in python you can use use one of the available libraries: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_run_a_python_code_in_the_GPU

CUDA might be the right for a NVIDIA GPU. For a guidance using it with the Anaconda Python distribution see https://weeraman.com/put-that-gpu-to-good-use-with-python-e5a437168c01

Answer (score 1):

Installing tensorflow gpu will make the script to detect gpu automatically. if it is not detecting the gpu, check the driver versions(Cuda and cudnn). If no version mismatch or errors occur, then the script can identify the gpu present and will run utilizing the gpu.