# I want to use the GPU instead of CPU while performing computations using PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm trying to switch the stress from CPU to GPU as my trusty RTX2070 can do it better than the CPU but I keep running into this problem and I'm quite new to AI so if you are kind enough to share some insights with me regarding any potential solution, it would be highly appreciated, thank you.

**I'm using PyTorch

Here's the code that I'm using :

```
# to measure run-time

# for csv dataset
import os
# to shuffle data
import random
# to get the alphabet
import string

# import statements for iterating over csv file
import cv2
# for plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# pytorch stuff
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from PIL import Image

# generate the targets 
# the targets are one hot encoding vectors
# print(torch.cuda.is_available())
nvcc_args = [
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_30,code=sm_30',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_35,code=sm_35',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_37,code=sm_37',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_50,code=sm_50',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_52,code=sm_52',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_60,code=sm_60',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_61,code=sm_61',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_70,code=sm_70',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_75,code=sm_75'
]

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
target = {}

# Initalize a target dict that has letters as its keys and empty one-hot encoding vectors of size 37 as its values
for letter in alphabet:
    target[letter] = [0] * 37

# Do the one-hot encoding for each letter now 
curr_pos = 0
for curr_letter in target.keys():
    target[curr_letter][curr_pos] = 1
    curr_pos += 1

# extra symbols 
symbols = ["space", "number", "period", "comma", "colon", "apostrophe", "hyphen", "semicolon", "question",
           "exclamation", "capitalize"]

# create vectors
for curr_symbol in symbols:
    target[curr_symbol] = [0] * 37

# create one-hot encoding vectors
for curr_symbol in symbols:
    target[curr_symbol][curr_pos] = 1
    curr_pos += 1

# collect all data from the csv file
data = []

for tgt in os.listdir("dataset"):
    if not tgt == ".DS_Store":
        for folder in os.listdir("dataset/" + tgt + "/Uploaded"):
            if not folder == ".DS_Store":
                for filename in os.listdir("dataset/" + tgt + "/Uploaded/" + folder):
                    if not filename == ".DS_Store":
                        # store the image and label
                        picture = []
                        curr_target = target[tgt]
                        image = Image.open("dataset/" + tgt + "/Uploaded/" + folder + "/" + filename)
                        image = image.convert('RGB')
                        # f.show()
                        image = np.array(image)
                        # resize image to 28x28x3
                        image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
                        # normalize to 0-1
                        image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
                        image = torch.from_numpy(image)
                        picture.append(image)
                        # convert the target to a long tensor
                        curr_target = torch.Tensor([curr_target])
                        picture.append(curr_target)
                        # append the current image & target
                        data.append(picture)

# create a dictionary of all the characters 
characters = alphabet + symbols

index2char = {}
number = 0
for char in characters:
    index2char[number] = char
    number += 1


# find the number of each character in a dataset
def num_chars(dataset, index2char):
    chars = {}
    for _, label in dataset:
        char = index2char[int(torch.argmax(label))]
        # update
        if char in chars:
            chars[char] += 1
        # initialize
        else:
            chars[char] = 1
    return chars


# Create dataloader objects

# shuffle all the data
random.shuffle(data)

# batch sizes for train, test, and validation
batch_size_train = 30
batch_size_test = 30
batch_size_validation = 30

# splitting data to get training, test, and validation sets
# change once get more data
# 1600 for train
train_dataset = data[:22000]
# test has 212
test_dataset = data[22000:24400]
# validation has 212
validation_dataset = data[24400:]

# create the dataloader objects
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=False)
validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=validation_dataset, batch_size=batch_size_validation,
                                                shuffle=True)

# to check if a dataset is missing a char
test_chars = num_chars(test_dataset, index2char)

num = 0
for char in characters:
    if char in test_chars:
        num += 1
    else:
        break
print(num)


class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.block1 = nn.Sequential(
            # 3x28x28
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,
                      out_channels=16,
                      kernel_size=5,
                      stride=1,
                      padding=2),
            # batch normalization
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True), 
            # 16x28x28
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
            # 16x14x14
            nn.LeakyReLU()
        )
        # 16x14x14
        self.block2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,
                      out_channels=32,
                      kernel_size=5,
                      stride=1,
                      padding=2),
            # batch normalization
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True), 
            # 32x14x14
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
            # 32x7x7
            nn.LeakyReLU()
        )
        # linearly 
        self.block3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 7, 100),
            # batch normalization
            # nn.BatchNorm1d(100),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(100, 37)
        )
        # 1x37

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.block1(x)
        out = self.block2(out)
        # flatten the dataset
        out = out.view(-1, 32 * 7 * 7)
        out = self.block3(out)
        return out


# convolutional neural network model
model = CNN()
model.cuda()


# print summary of the neural network model to check if everything is fine. 
print(model)
print("# parameter: ", sum([param.nelement() for param in model.parameters()]))

# setting the learning rate
learning_rate = 1e-4

# Using a variable to store the cross entropy method
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Using a variable to store the optimizer 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# list of all train_losses 
train_losses = []

# list of all validation losses 
validation_losses = []

# for loop that iterates over all the epochs
num_epochs = 20
for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    # variables to store/keep track of the loss and number of iterations
    train_loss = 0
    num_iter_train = 0

    # train the model
    model.train()

    # Iterate over train_loader
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # need to permute so that the images are of size 3x28x28 
        # essential to be able to feed images into the model
        images = images.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)

        # Zero the gradient buffer
        # resets the gradient after each epoch so that the gradients don't add up
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward, get output
        outputs = model(images)

        # convert the labels from one hot encoding vectors into integer values 
        labels = labels.view(-1, 37)
        y_true = torch.argmax(labels, 1)

        # calculate training loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, y_true)

        # Backward (computes all the gradients)
        loss.backward()

        # Optimize
        # loops through all parameters and updates weights by using the gradients 
        # takes steps backwards to optimize (to reach the minimum weight)
        optimizer.step()
        # update the training loss and number of iterations
        train_loss += loss.data
        num_iter_train += 1

    print('Epoch: {}'.format(epoch + 1))
    print('Training Loss: {:.4f}'.format(train_loss / num_iter_train))
    # append training loss over all the epochs
    train_losses.append(train_loss / num_iter_train)

    # evaluate the model
    model.eval()

    # variables to store/keep track of the loss and number of iterations
    validation_loss = 0
    num_iter_validation = 0

    # Iterate over validation_loader
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(validation_loader):
        # need to permute so that the images are of size 3x28x28 
        # essential to be able to feed images into the model
        images = images.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)

        # Forward, get output
        outputs = model(images)

        # convert the labels from one hot encoding vectors to integer values
        labels = labels.view(-1, 37)
        y_true = torch.argmax(labels, 1)

        # calculate the validation loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, y_true)

        # update the training loss and number of iterations
        validation_loss += loss.data
        num_iter_validation += 1

    print('Validation Loss: {:.4f}'.format(validation_loss / num_iter_validation))
    # append all validation_losses over all the epochs
    validation_losses.append(validation_loss / num_iter_validation)

    num_iter_test = 0
    correct = 0

    # Iterate over test_loader
    for images, labels in test_loader:
        # need to permute so that the images are of size 3x28x28 
        # essential to be able to feed images into the model
        images = images.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)

        # Forward
        outputs = model(images)

        # convert the labels from one hot encoding vectors into integer values 
        labels = labels.view(-1, 37)
        y_true = torch.argmax(labels, 1)

        # find the index of the prediction
        y_pred = torch.argmax(outputs, 1).type('torch.FloatTensor')

        # convert to FloatTensor
        y_true = y_true.type('torch.FloatTensor')

        # find the mean difference of the comparisons
        correct += torch.sum(torch.eq(y_true, y_pred).type('torch.FloatTensor'))

    print('Accuracy on the test set: {:.4f}%'.format(correct / len(test_dataset) * 100))
    print()


# learning curve function
def plot_learning_curve(train_losses, validation_losses):
    # plot the training and validation losses
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Number of Epochs')
    plt.plot(train_losses, label="training")
    plt.plot(validation_losses, label="validation")
    plt.legend(loc=1)


# plot the learning curve
plt.title("Learning Curve (Loss vs Number of Epochs)")
plot_learning_curve(train_losses, validation_losses)

torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model1.pth")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use your trusty search engine to find a library to run code on your GPU?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run python code with support of GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650577/how-to-run-python-code-with-support-of-gpu)

Comment: @JoshJ Thanks for the link but as far as I know, PyTorch supports GPU computations through the usage of the func .cuda(), can you please be more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also using a trusty RTX 2070 and this is how I do GPU acceleration (for 1 GPU):

```
cuda_ = "cuda:0"
device = torch.device(cuda_ if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = CNN()
model.to(device)
```

This is the most up-to-date and recommended way to do GPU acceleration, as it gives more flexibility (don't need to amend code even when GPU isn't available). You would do the same to pass your images into the GPU vram, via `images = images.to(device)`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for sharing the solution with me, just to make sure we're on the same page, is it mandatory to transfer the images as well to the GPU or can I stick with only the model, because I have tried your solution and it resulted in the same output and then when tried to play with the images as well got the following answer:

RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward

Comment: Yeah you should pass the labels to device as well when calculating the loss (it expects that both input and target be on the same device: cpu/gpu). And yes, it is necessary for acceleration or else you would need to use `pin_memory=True`. Here's a relevant thread: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-all-data-into-gpu-for-training/27609

Comment: Thank you for the extra layer of info, I tweaked some parameters and now the training is much faster and the CPU is chillin' around 25%. Interesting though that the GPU is not used as much as I thought, merely 4% with an external monitor connected to the GPU as well so..I think it's no struggle for the RTX.

Once again thank you for taking the time to explain me the whole situation, wish you all the best!